# Converting text file to a video with speech

Tags: video, video-editor, editing

I have several long text files and I'm looking forward to convert them into a video with synced text-to-speech voice. Because texts are long, an animation/slide/pagination will be required on video. Also if possible I would like to add background image too.

A good example can be seen [here](http://bit.do/euWvy).

Is there any way to automate this task? And also the result videos license should allow me to freely distribute videos. If automation is not an option, how can I create this videos easily?

Comment: Have you looked at [AviSynth](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page)/[VapourSynth](http://www.vapoursynth.com/)? They're able to generate videos using code (AviSynth has its own language, while VapourSynth users Python)